# Как создать два ровных ряда в recycler-view?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Нужен recycler view (grid layout) с двумя ровными рядами картинок (отступы по сторонам recycler view и между картинками должны быть одинаковыми). Как это можно сделать?

Вот код layout, на котором работает recycler-view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tile_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@drawable/kfc" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

А вот что получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы запилил grid layout manager в 2 столбца. Расхардкодил wight и height на match parent и wrap content и убрал бы margin bottom 16 dp как минимум. В общем привел бы в порядок разметку

Comment: @Романыч, у grid layout manager уже стоит значение 2. А если пытаться использовать match parent и wrap content, то картинки вообще пропадают.

Comment: из представленного кода не видно какое стоит значение, но  очевидно что проблемы у вас с разметкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount;
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; 

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; 
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; 
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
int spanCount = 2; // 2 columns
int spacing = 50; // 50px
boolean includeEdge = true;
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge));
```